# PHP process JSON array

Tags: php, json, arrays

How do I process this JSONArray?
I receive it through a POST from an Android app.

```
"[
    "Itemz",
    {
        "id": "1",
        "idviz": "3",
        "pux": "100.00",
        "umx": "PCS",
        "cantx": "3",
        "name": "Item 1 name"
    },
    "Itemz",
    {
        "id": "3",
        "idviz": "3",
        "pux": "230.00",
        "umx": "PCS",
        "cantx": "2",
        "name": "Item 2 name"
    },
    "Itemz",
    {
        "id": "7",
        "idviz": "3",
        "pux": "87.23",
        "umx": "LTR",
        "cantx": "6",
        "name": "Item 3 name"
    }
]"
```

How do I access the items inside this JSON Array?
I need to break it apart so I can build mysql insert statements. As you can assume each "Items" is an Item that must be inserted in a table.

Thank you

Comment: check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an extra quote at the beginning and end of yones answer in the json, and also an extra double quote at the beginning and end of the OPs json.  Since json uses double quotes, you need to encapsulate the entire json string in single quotes. Try this:

```
$json = '[
    "Itemz",
    {
        "id": "1",
        "idviz": "3",
        "pux": "100.00",
        "umx": "PCS",
        "cantx": "3",
        "name": "Item 1 name"
    },
    "Itemz",
    {
        "id": "3",
        "idviz": "3",
        "pux": "230.00",
        "umx": "PCS",
        "cantx": "2",
        "name": "Item 2 name"
    },
    "Itemz",
    {
        "id": "7",
        "idviz": "3",
        "pux": "87.23",
        "umx": "LTR",
        "cantx": "6",
        "name": "Item 3 name"
    }
]';

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($json));
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

json_decode
 will parse the json string into an array